# Need some javascript advice

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at some javascript code and trying to understand how it works.

It contains underscores against some of the functions but I can't see Lodash or Underscore included so I'm confused about how that is working. Here's an example...

```
theme.Sections.prototype = _.assignIn({}, theme.Sections.prototype, {
  _createInstance: function(container, constructor) {...
```

Can anyone help me understand how that is working?
Here's a link to the site that's using the code so that you can see the whole thing working...
https://debut-demo.myshopify.com/

Edit: It is  **_.assignIn** that I'm confused about. I can't see Lodash loaded so not sure how that is working?

Comment: `_` is a function. It's inside `vendor.js` and it's minified. Dunno what it is but my guess is it's something like lodash. In fact, it might be a custom lodash package (where you only include the functions you want).

Comment: Everyone here needs some JavaScript advice. Please describe clearly in the question title what it is you need advice about.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I'm aware, it's generally used to indicate a private variable (but doesn't actually provide any privacy, just a convention).

It's discussed briefly here, though they're advised against: http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

Comment: Actually true - I'm not sure what OP refers to - the `_.assignIn` is definitely some library. But the `_createInstance` is a "private" property.

Comment: Yeah it is assignIn that I'm confused about. Can't see a library loaded when looking at the network tab of Chrome dev tools

Comment: @user736129 please see documentation here https://lodash.com/docs/#assignIn

Comment: @user736129 it isn't loaded as lodash - it's bundled in `vendor.js`. For how I know is - opened the console, typed in `_` (yes, just that) -> hit enter, so it was evaluated and told me it's a function reference -> clicked on the function reference and it got me to the definition inside `vendor.js`